# C#: .Config File and write issue in program folder

Tags: c#, config

i use the ConfigurationManager to store some app-configurationvalues.
Since i start my app from the program folder i cant save config-changes...

I cant write in the program folder...
I know that its good practise to store data in %AppData% or %Temp%, but i want my config-File in the same folder as the executable.

How can i handle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 options:

- run your process with administrator privileges (not good if you don't need them)
- put your exe somewhere not in `Program Files`
- store your config in `AppData` (best)

Comment: ok, if there is no other option i have to save the configfile @ AppData ;)